# scikit-learn: Support Vector Machine. Precision and/or accuracy?

Tags: python, statistics, scikit-learn, svm, data-science

I am trying to figure whether the code I use calculates precision or accuracy or both. Since I only have a little background in statistics (in another language) I don't really understand the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision) covering that topic.

Concretely I use following Python code:

`from sklearn import svm, cross_validation
clf = svm.SVC(kernel=kernel, C=C)
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, FeatureMatrix, np.squeeze(LabelMatrix), cv=d_inds)`

Documentation for the [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html) functions can be found here :

- [`sklearn.svm.SVC`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html)
- [`sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `cross_val_score` uses the `score` method of the classifier (usually this is accuracy). If you want to specifiy another metric, pass it in the `scoring` parameter, as is `cross_val_score(clf, X, y, scoring = 'precision')`. For a full list of scoring options, take a look at http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html